# Use Powershell to Find Stored Procedures in SSIS Packages

Tags: powershell, ssis, full-text-search, text-search

I'm attempting to using PowerShell to search all SSIS Packages within a directory, and return the following:

- The path and name of the file
- The line containing the stored procedure name, i.e. "exec mystoredproc"

The criteria I'd like to use to search is simply "exec", or "exec or execute" if possible, and I'd like the space at the end of the string following exec to be the delimiter as far as what is returned.

I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "exec" | group path | select name
```

However this only returns the file name, not the additional text that is required.

If there is a better way to do this than PowerShell, I'm open to it, but based on what I've found so far this seemed to be the right path. Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
Having continued to research, I've found that this command

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern exec,execute | Select filename,linenumber
```

seems to give the correct file and line number for the commands I'm looking for. Is there some way to have the line that the linenumber references print instead of the number? I've looked at ForEach and Get-Content, but can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that should prove useful for you:

```
function Get-StoredProcedure {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSObject')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo[]] $Path = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File)
    )

    process {
        foreach ($item in $Path) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'Path'    = Split-Path -Parent -Path $item.FullName
                'Name'    = $item.Name
                'Command' = ($item | Select-String -Pattern 'exec(ute)?\s[^\s]+').Matches.Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will go through whatever `FileInfo` objects you pass to it (do note to use `-File` with `Get-ChildItem` or filter out the `PSIsContainer` property).  It returns an object with the path, filename, and command in a string in the form of `exec(ute) <contiguous non-spaces>`

Comment: This is returning Execute and a letter (Execute P, Execute A, etc) for the command. I was looking for Execute thenextworduntilaspace. Can the string pattern be modified to this effect? Also, it seems to ONLY be finding "execute", however I know for a fact that "exec" exists as well.

Comment: @Jake Oops, that's a mistake in my regex.  I think I've corrected it now.

Comment: Much better, thank you! One more request - is there any way to have each command show on a different line (with the Path & Name also reprinted on each line)?

Comment: @Jake It's just an object so you can do whatever you want: `foreach ($item in (Get-StoredProcedure)) { $item.Command; $item.Path + ' ' + $item.Name }`